# Can access to file mapped memory ever last indefinitely

Tags: unix, x86, x86-64, freebsd

Is it ever possible for a read to a memory location to be prolonged indefinitely (and for another thread to allow the read to complete after an arbitrary timeout)?

For example, with blocking sockets, we can get a process to halt when using the `read` system call:

```
fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
read(fd, buffer, 256);
```

Usually we can't `mmap` sockets, but I would essentially like the same thing to happen when accessing memory directly:

```
int x = *(int *)map;
```

I am aware of techniques to make memory access take longer, like using `madvise` to page out memory before accessing it, but I am looking for a method of getting this to last indefinitely.

I've considered using `mmap` on a file, and then "locking" that file, but couldn't find an appropriate interface for this. The `flock` system call doesn't seem to work this way.

Specifically, I am interested in FreeBSD for x86-64 architecture, but answers for other Unix-like systems such as Linux, and other architectures would also be appreciated.

Comment: If you want "blocking" memory access, you could try mmap()ing a file on an NFS mount, and performing some real random access on this memory.

Comment: If the file is on a custom [`FUSE` mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), you can get any arbitrary behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `mprotect(..., PROT_NONE)` to mark the page containing `map` as not accessible.  When you then try to access it, a page fault occurs and `SIGSEGV` will be raised.

You can install a handler for `SIGSEGV`, declared with the extra `siginfo_t` argument.  Look at the `si_addr` member of this struct to check whether the faulting address matches `map`; this lets you distinguish accesses to this address from other faults that are actual bugs in your code (e.g. NULL dereference).  If it does, then the signal handler can wait until told to continue by the other thread.  When ready, call `mprotect` with `PROT_READ` (or `PROT_WRITE` as appropriate) and return from the signal handler; the faulting instruction is restarted and execution continues.

This is a rather ugly hack, and I'd suggest a good hard look as to why you think you need to do this.  Your question seems like it might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I've implemented your suggestion, and it works for userland access (EG: `*(int *)buffer = 0;`), however it doesn't freeze writes from kernel, which was my ultimate goal (EG: `getcontext((ucontext_t *)buffer);`).

Comment: @CHRIS: Kernel mode is a completely different animal.  If that was your goal I wish you had said so.  As it is, you should probably ask a new question.

Comment: I will accept your answer, since it works for the question I originally described. Thanks.